# Is it possible to set VLC media player show the length of a video?

Tags: vlc-media-player

the bottom right of the VLC media player shows the length of the video left. Is it possible to have the player show the length of a whole video?

[image]

there is a workaround for this step backward and then forward, the player would show the time on the screen, but it is boring. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is set by default, but you can go into the `Tools` --> `Customise Interface` menu to change what "widgets" are shown on the time bar.

[image]

I believe the `Total/Remaining Time` widget is what you're looking for. Just drag it from the list at the bottom onto the toolbar in the location you want it to go. The interface is like dragging and dropping bookmarks on the Chrome/Firefox bookmarks bar.