# How to let VLC media player (on Mac) show total duration of video near the progress bar?

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player

[image: VLC Progress Bar]

On Mac, the VLC media player progress bar defaults to show the elapsed or remaining time of a video (in non-full-screen mode). Is there a way to make it show the total time of a video **in addition** to the elapsed time? I know [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1502526/is-it-possible-to-set-vlc-media-player-show-the-length-of-a-video) talks about how to show this on Windows, but I need to know how to get this done on Mac (since the Customize Interface option isn't available on Mac).

Comment: It shows it in fullscreen [native or VLC's own] because it then uses the Quicktime interface if you move your mouse.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know that. The purpose of this post is to ask for means to showing that in non-full-screen mode.

Comment: Not possible. The Mac & Windows apps are totally different in many respects, not limited to UI customisation.